# Cordova universal links on a different activity

Tags: firebase, cordova, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I am implementing Firebase Authentication in my Cordova application. The android app integrates Cordova in an activity that is not the main/launcher activity. Due to this, a required dependency plugin "cordova-universal-links-plugin" does not target the correct activity (it targets the main/launcher activity).

Is there a way to specify the target activity for universal-links? If not, how can I make a workaround/hack to fix this issue (as the plugin is not being maintained anymore)?

Comment: You should actually use `cordova-plugin-deeplinks` as the original one is deprecated and is not being maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known method of specifying the target activity for `cordova-universal-links-plugin`. You can create a workaround by running scripts before/after `cordova prepare`.

The fix will work like this:

1. You have to rearrange your activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` so that the target activity is ordered before the main/launcher activity. I am assuming the target activity initially looks like this:

```xml
<activity android:name=".CordovaActivity">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2. Now, you'll write two NodeJS scripts: `before_prepare.js` and `after_prepare.js`.

   a) `before_prepare.js`: This will add an `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` after the `<category />` tag for your target activity. Since "CordovaActivity" is temporarily also a main/launcher activity & is before  the actual main activity, the universal-links plugin should target it instead.

   b) `after_prepare.js`: We want this to run after the plugin applies the universal-links intent-filters to your target activity. It will remove the `<action />` tag you've added. This is necessary since Android can't allow two main activities.
3. Add `before_prepare.js` to your project-level `config.xml` as a `before_prepare` Cordova hook.
4. Because Cordova runs your hooks before the plugin hooks, you can't add `after_prepare.js` as an `after_prepare` Cordova hook. That's because the `<action />` tag would be removed before the universal-links plugin gets a chance to run. Instead, you'll have to run it after the `cordova prepare` command. I recommend doing this by using an npm script (`npm run prepare`) that runs `after_prepare.js` after `cordova prepare`.

My implementation depends on `elementtree` for XML editing (it is also used by Cordova internally):

```
npm install elementtree
```

`before_prepare.js`:

```js
const et = require('elementtree')
const fs = require('fs')

const MANIFEST_FILE = '/.../CordovaProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'

/**
 * Add main action intent from `SurkartaActivity`.
 *
 * @param {ElementTree} manifestTree
 */
function addMainAction (manifestTree) {
    const intentFilterElement = manifestTree.find("./application/activity[@android:name='.SurakartaActivity']")
        .getchildren()[0]

    const mainActionElement = et.SubElement(intentFilterElement, 'action')
    mainActionElement.set('android:name', 'android.intent.action.MAIN')
}

// Cordova hook executes module.exports
module.exports = function () {
    const manifestTree = et.parse(fs.readFileSync(MANIFEST_FILE, 'utf8'))
    addMainAction(manifestTree)

    console.log(manifestTree.write())
    fs.writeFileSync(MANIFEST_FILE, manifestTree.write())
}
```

`after_prepare.js`:

```js
const et = require('elementtree')
const fs = require('fs')

const MANIFEST_FILE = '/.../CordovaProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'

/**
 * Remove main action intent from `SurkartaActivity`.
 *
 * @param {ElementTree} manifestTree
 */
function stripMainAction (manifestTree) {
    const intentFilterElement = manifestTree.find("./application/activity[@android:name='.SurakartaActivity']")
        .getchildren()[0]
    intentFilterElement.remove(intentFilterElement.getchildren()[1])
}

function hey () {
    const manifestTree = et.parse(fs.readFileSync(MANIFEST_FILE, 'utf8'))
    stripMainAction(manifestTree)
    fs.writeFileSync(MANIFEST_FILE, manifestTree.write())
}

module.exports = hey

// This isn't an Cordova hook, so run it manually
hey()
```

Changes to existing files:

`config.xml`:

```xml
<hook type="before_prepare" src="./path/to/before_prepare.js" />
```

`package.json`:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "cordova prepare; node ./path/to/after_prepare.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "elementtree": "@latest" /* npm install elementtree should do this for you */
  }
}
```